# Java on Mac OS FileNotFound if path contatins non latin characters

Tags: java, macos, file

Good news everyone.

I found intersted problem with java on my Mac OS.

I put file with name from nonlatin characters to folder test, full path is **/Users/dnelepov/Downloads/test/тест изображение.png**

[image]

As u can see **file exists!**

Next i wrote some code to view all files on folder **/Users/dnelepov/Downloads/test/** and open file for read (for example):

```
File dirF = new File("/Users/dnelepov/Downloads/test/");
            File[] files = dirF.listFiles();
            for (File oneF : files) {
                System.out.println("FILE:" + oneF);
                if (oneF.exists()){
                    System.out.println("EXISTS:"+oneF);
                }
            }
```

But next i got this:

[image]

As you can see line EXSIS: never printed, but file founded!

Also printind system properties get:

**file.encoding=UTF-8**

**p.s.**

I ask similar type question before [Java java.io.filenotfoundexception for file path with cyrillic characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968299/java-java-io-filenotfoundexception-for-file-path-with-cyrillic-characters) - **but** i think this problem not for only Cyrillic characters - but for all non latin languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 7 you can use java.nio.file API, it works properly with cyrillic paths:

```
    Path path = Paths.get("/Users/dnelepov/Downloads/test/");
    Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path oneF, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("FILE:" + oneF);
            if (Files.exists(oneF)) {
                System.out.println("EXISTS:" + oneF);
            }
            return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Add this answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16968299/java-java-io-filenotfoundexception-for-file-path-with-cyrillic-characters?rq=1

Comment: Just to recap: new FileInputStream(path.toFile) has this problem but Files.newInputStream(path) doesn't.